# Stripe Test API for payments not working on Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, web-applications, stripe-payments

I am developing an app using Ruby on Rails for my study course. For payments I installed Stripe on the app using a test API and it worked fine, but then I installed it on another app and used the same test API. When I click on Buy Now it doesn't go to the Stripe payment page and I get a message "Waiting for q.stripe.com". Can I use my same Test API for two apps or is it a different problem?

My code is follows:
In the places_controller.rb

```
def show
    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      customer_email: current_user.email,
      line_items:  [{
        name: @place.name,
        description: @place.description,
        amount: @place.price,
        currency: 'aud',
        quantity: 1
      }],
      payment_intent_data: {
        metadata: {
          user_id: current_user.id,
          place_id: @place.id
        }
      },
      success_url: "#{root_url}payments/success?placeId=#{@place.id}",
      # todo - check if we can use places_path
      cancel_url: "#{root_url}places"
    )

    @sessions_id = session.id
  end
```

and in the show.html.erb for Places View

```
<button data-stripe="payment">
Buy Now!
</button>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
  document
    .querySelector("[data-stripe='payment']")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
      const stripe = Stripe(
        "<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :public_key) %>"
      )

      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: "<%= @session_id %>"
      })
    })
</script>
```

stripe.rb in config/initializers

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :secret_key)
```

Comment: What do you mean by using a "test API" in two apps? Do you mean using your test key in two places? That should be fine, as long as the PK and SK are a matched pair for the same account. This sounds like something else is going on. More details about the error and how to reach it would be helpful.

Comment: I am creating an accommodation app. Yes I did copy both keys and created a 'Buy Now' button. But when I click on that it is not going to the Stripe page. I have attached an image below of my console.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your test / production keys on multiple applications, if that is what you're trying to ask. It would help to check the console for any error messages.

Comment: I first copied the the two keys and put it in credentials, then I did the code above in Stripe.rb, and everything else as above, then created the 'Buy Now' button. When I go and click on it it doesn't go to the Stripe page. There is a message that appears "Waiting for q.stripe.com" and then it disappears. I don't get any errors on the console, the following message is there after failing to connect to Stripe page.

https://imgur.com/a/m4bWYAe

Comment: Any chance you're hosting this application on a server? Please make sure it can contact Stripe's domains: https://stripe.com/docs/ips

Comment: Yes I am using a Rails Server and connecting to Stripe Domain. https://js.stripe.com/v3/

Comment: Can you attempt to click Buy Now again and observe the network logs in the browser developer console? Is it able to contact Stripe? Because if there's anything wrong with the Checkout Session, you'd have at least been redirected to Stripe and shown an error message.

Comment: Thanx for you help. I attempted again but there is no message or error message on the console. When I hit buy now on localhost:3000 there is a message 'request processing' and then waiting for q.stripe.com appears and dissappears.

Comment: Can you verify if a session id is correctly generated?

Comment: Yes, it comes up in the params.

Comment: Okay, assuming everything is implemented correctly like you described, then the only issue I can think of is your server can't contact Stripe. Because the `redirectToCheckout` would've redirected you to Stripe, and errors will be shown on their website for reasons like invalid session, etc. But if you're not getting redirected at all, it's worth to check if your server is allowing in/outbound traffic to/from Stripe.

Comment: I got an error when deploying to Heroku; as follows and this can be the reason for Stripe not working. https://imgur.com/a/y323LgV

Comment: Yup, that's nothing to do with Stripe. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help for this query and your time. Mistakes was in Stripe I had 'Session' in one place and 'Sessions' in another place.

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out.